# Rebus Saga Unit Test SagaFixture Event Handlers Not Firing

Tags: .net, unit-testing, rebus, saga

I am trying to unit test a saga with Rebus. Everything was going great until I tried using the events on the SagaFixture for tracking whether or not certain actions had occurred.

For example, I have this code:

```
        [SetUp]
        public void SetUp()
        {
            _mockSomeService = new Mock<ISomeService>();
            _bus = new FakeBus();

            _saga = new SomeSaga(_bus, _mockSomeService);
        }

            [Test]
            public void SagaWillCompleteIfActionIsNoResponse()
            {
                _mockSomeService.Setup(x => x.GetSomeValue(
                    It.IsAny<int>())).Returns(SomeResonse.NoResponse.ToString());

                using var fixture = SagaFixture.For(() => _saga);
                var eventHandlerCalled = false;
                fixture.Deleted += d => eventHandlerCalled = true;
                fixture.Deliver(_message, deliveryTimeoutSeconds: _deliveryTimeoutSeconds);
                Assert.That(eventHandlerCalled, Is.True);
            }
```

Now in the Saga itself, the logic in the handler for the type of message I am sending just calls MarkAsComplete(). I would expect that to trigger my defined "Delete" event handler from my test, but it doesn't. What am I missing here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you verified that your handler code is in fact being hit, when the message is handled?

If so, could you update the question to include the code in your handler?

Comment: Hi, I found the samples in the Rebus.TestHelpers project. I noticed that the code first calls a saga with a successful message and THEN calls the saga with another message to trigger the saga deletion. So I assume I have to do the same thing, right? In order for the delete to happen, it seems like the in-memory storage needs to have the saga in the first place prior to the new message.

Comment: Yes it does  in a way it makes a lot of sense: The saga instance needs to exist before it can cease to exist

Comment: Following this suggested patten ended up working. Thank you!